# Python argv not working

Tags: python

I'm new to python and i'm just reading practicing different things and i'm trying to figure out why argv isn't working for me

```
from sys import argv
script, bike, car, bus = argv

print ("The script is called:"), script
print ("The first variable is:"), bike
print ("The second variable is "), car
print ("Your third variable is : "),bus
```

I'm getting an error of need more than 1 value to unpack

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex13.py", line 6, in <module>
    script, bike, car, bus = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I am running my example program from the command-line by calling:

```
python ex13.py
```

Comment: First, always put the actual exception (with traceback) in your question, don't just describe it vaguely.

Comment: Second, how are you _running_ this script? If you aren't passing it any arguments (e.g., you're just doing `python3 myscript.py` or double-clicking `myscript.py` in Explorer/whatever), then `argv` will only have 1 element, not 4, which would give you exactly the error you're seeing.

Comment: ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack. I'm using pycharm to write the code and run it, and i'm also running it again in windows powershell

Comment: That's still not the *exception (with traceback)*, because you didn't include the traceback. Also, edit it into your question, don't post it as a comment. And finally, "I'm using pycharm to write the code and run it, and i'm also running it again in windows powershell" doesn't answer my question: show the actual Windows PowerShell line that you use to run it. If you aren't passing any arguments there, that's the problem.

Comment: Your `print` statement isn't correct either...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "ex13.py", line 6, in <module> script, bike, car, bus = argv ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack  . Pycharm is an ide and i just click run and it runs the program, but in powershell i type in python ex13.py and that runs the program

Comment: I don't know how else to explain "edit it into your question". Click the [edit] button.

Comment: @Zizouz212, care to explain?

Comment: @jumpman8947 Id did in my updated response.

Comment: You still haven't put the information about how you run your program into your question. Since that's the actual cause of the actual problem here, that makes your question useless.

Comment: @abarnert its in the comment where i say i use pycharm and click run, and i also use windows powershell and run the command python ex13.py

Comment: Again, you have to put it _in the question_, not just in comments. Comments are hard to dig through, don't have complete formatting, can get deleted at any point, are ignored by the search index, etc. Read the help; it explains all of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example is better written as (*to cope with arbitrary usages*):

```
from sys import argv
script, args = argv[0], argv[1:]

print("The script is called: ", script)
for i, arg in enumerate(args):
    print("Arg {0:d}: {1:s}".format(i, arg))
```

The reason you'd be getting an error (*place show Traceback*) is because you're calling your script with fewer arguments than you are trying to "unpack".

See: [Python Packing and Unpacking](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples#Packing_and_Unpacking) and [Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) where it says:

> This is called, appropriately enough, sequence unpacking and works for
>   any sequence on the right-hand side. Sequence unpacking requires the
>   list of variables on the left to have the same number of elements as
>   the length of the sequence. Note that multiple assignment is really
>   just a combination of tuple packing and sequence unpacking.

To demonstrate what's going on with your example adn eht error you get back:

```
>>> argv = ["./foo.py", "1"]
>>> script, a = argv
>>> script
'./foo.py'
>>> a
'1'
>>> script, a, b = argv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

*The error should be obvious here; You are trying to unpack more values than you have!*

To fix your example I'd do this:

```
from sys import argv

if len(argv) < 4:
    print ("usage: {0:s} <bike> <car> <bus>".format(script))
    raise SystemExit(-1)

script, bike, car, bus = argv

print ("The script is called:", script)
print ("The first variable is:", bike)
print ("The second variable is ", car)
print ("Your third variable is : ", bus)
```

**Update:** I just noticed this; but all your `print()`(s) are wrong. You need to either use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) or put the argument inside the `print()` function.

Comment: Thanks the book i'm using to learn python didn't really explain what what python packing was in much detail, which explains why i was so far from the correct concept.

Comment: Then I'd say that's not a very good book to learn from. Personally I find the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) invaluable.

Answer (score 3):

> Pycharm is an ide and i just click run and it runs the program, but in powershell i type in python ex13.py and that runs the program

OK, then you aren't passing any arguments. So, what were you *expecting* to find as as the first, second, and third arguments? PowerShell isn't going to guess what bike, car, and bus you wanted to pass the program, any more than it's going to go out and buy you a bike, car, and bus. So, if you want to run this program with arguments representing your bike, car, and bus, you have to actually do that:

```
python ex13.py CR325 Elise VW
```

Then your script will output those arguments.

Well, actually, it may not, because your `print` calls are wrong. If this is Python 2.7, those parentheses don't do anything, so you'll see:

```
The script is called: ex13.py
The first variable is: CR325
The second variable is  Elise
The third variable is :  VW
```

If it's Python 3.x, the parentheses wrap the arguments to the `print`, just like any other function, so the `, script` and so forth aren't part of the `print`, so you'll just see:

```
The script is called: 
The first variable is: 
The second variable is 
The third variable is :
```

Comment: Great explanation on all the things that *could* go wrong with the initila implementation :) +1

Comment: Indeed great explanation, i'm new to python so i didn't know about the parentheses and print call variations.